# The minimax function calculating incorrectly for the 2nd board test

Tags: python, minimax

[The assignment telling what I have to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Cxj.png)

So I'm following a CodeHS course for building an AI tic tac toe game, however while I was trying to finish up my minimax function, it returns wrong answers for the 2nd board test(the tests at the bottom) I don't know why. Help me out please!

Also, since the site is asking me to fill out random words, im just going to type random stuff here:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

```
board = []
##Copy your check_tie and check_win functions from the previous lesson
# and any other function needed for those functions to work.
def check_col_win(player):
    if board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] == player:
        return True
    elif board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] == player:
        return True
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] == player:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def check_row_win(player):
    if board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] == player:
        return True
    elif board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] == player:
        return True
    elif board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] == player:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def check_diag_win(player):
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == player:
        return True
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == player:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
def check_win(player):
    return check_col_win(player) or check_row_win(player) or check_diag_win(player)

def check_tie():
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == "-":
                return False
    return True
##Copy over your place_player function
def is_valid_move(row, col):
    if board[row][col] == "-":
        return True
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid move")
        return False

#places player on row,col on the board
def place_player(player, row, col):
    if is_valid_move(row, col):
        board[row][col] = player


def minimax(player, optimalRow = -1, optimalCol = -1):
    #copy your basecase here:
    if check_win("O"):
        return (10, optimalRow, optimalCol)
    if check_win("X"):
        return (-10, optimalRow, optimalCol)
    if check_tie():
        return (0, optimalRow, optimalCol)
        
    #implement recursive case
    if player == "O":
        best = -10000
        for i in range(3):
            for a in range(3):
                if board[i][a] == "-":
                    place_player("O", i, a)
                    best, optimalRow, optimalCol = max(best, (minimax("X")[0])), (minimax("X")[1]), (minimax("X")[2])
                    board[i][a] = "-"
                   
        return (best, optimalRow, optimalCol)
        
    if player == "X":
        worst = 10000
        for k in range (3):
            for l in range (3):
                if board[k][l] == "-":
                    place_player("X", k, l)
                    worst, optimalRow, optimalCol = min(worst, (minimax("O")[0])), (minimax("O")[1]), (minimax("O")[2])
                    board[k][l] = "-"
       
        return (worst, optimalRow, optimalCol)
        
        
    
##Don't edit this code
# It checks to see if your minimax function is working correctly
def print_board():
    print("\n")
    print("\t0\t\t1\t\t2")
    count = 0
    for item in board:
        row = ""
        for space in item:
            row += "\t" + space + "\t"
        print(count,row + "\n")
        count+= 1
board.append(["O","X","-"])
board.append(["-","X","-"])
board.append(["-","-","-"])
print("Calling minimax('O') on this board:")
print_board()
print("Minimax should return (0, 2, 1):", minimax("O"))
board.clear()
print("Calling minimax('O') on this board:")
board.append(["O","X","-"])
board.append(["-","X","X"])
board.append(["-","O","-"])
print_board()
print("Minimax should return (0, 1, 0) ", minimax("O"))
board.clear()
print("Calling minimax('O') on this board:")
board.append(["O","X","X"])
board.append(["O","X","X"])
board.append(["-","O","-"])
print_board()
print("Minimax should return (10, 2, 0) ", minimax("O"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the question is very vague and you should let us know what the "wrong answer" is and what you expect instead. So here is some guess:

You make the very common mistake of always delivering a winning score when "O" is winning, no matter who's turn it is. Minimax should send a winning score when "O" is winning AND it is "O" turn, OR if "X" is winning AND it is "X" turn.

If "O" is winning AND it is "X" turn it should return losing score, OR if "X"´is winning AND it is "O" turn.

This should probable fix your issue.